# Relaying the incoming token downstream to other services

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to understand 100% how a Resource Server works, relaying the incoming token downstream to other services.

I have a microservice architecture with spring boot eureka, with Bearer authentication against an @EnableAuthorizationServer. 
I use an Edge Service in zuul with @EnableZuulProxy and @EnableOAuth2Sso for request entry, and I wanted security to be centralized at that point, but of course, I can't leave the microservices without security and each of them is an @EnableResourceServer.

Everything works ok.

The question is: 
Either with a security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri pointing to the oauth server or to the edge service, that bearer token is always validated against the oauth server, i.e. if it passes through 10 microservices a request, will it validate the token 10 times against the oauth server? 
Isn't there any way that I don't have to request 10 times to the oauth server if the token is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, 
It seems that for a **Bearer token** type, it is always necessary to authenticate on each resource server against the authentication server.

The solution is to use JWT tokens.

As explained in:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/02/client-creds-with-spring-boot#extra-credit-reduce-the-number-of-calls-to-the-authorization-server

*We use signed JWTs which means you can validate them locally instead of making an additional request from the API service to the authorization server on each request.*

[image: Diagram JWT]

That's it.